# Numerically solving these second order ODEs

Tags: differential-equations

I’m trying to solve these three ODE equations together

```
 eqs = {(x'[t]/x[t])^2 == z[t] + H0^2 (Yr0 x[t]^(-4) + H0^2 Ym0 x[t]^(-3) + Y0),
         2 x''[t]/x[t] + (x'[t]/x[t])^2 == -z[t] + H0^2 Yr0 x[t]^(-4) - H0^2 Y0,     
         x'[t]/x[t] + (x'[t]/x[t])^2 == -z[t] + Lam}
```

Any help how to solve numerically using `NDSolve` to get `x[t]`, and `z[t]`, because it seems there are many ways to eliminate one of the two variables say $\dot{z}$ and get the other  variable.

The boundry conditions are :`x[0]==0.001,x'[0]==1`

The values of the constants are:

$ H0 = 10^{-8},  Yr0=10^{-5}, Ym0 = 0.3, Y0= 0.7, Lam=10^{-3}$

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: I do not see `a[t]` anywhere.  Also your code has lots of syntax errors. For starter an equation should have `==` and not `=`. Try to paste the input form.  Also you seem to have 3 ode's (but not sure, due to the syntax error I get), but want to solve for 2 dependent variables? (which I think you meant `x[t]` and `z[t]`

Comment: The system seems overdetermined, is not it? If one subtracts the third equation from the second one, the equation with respect to x only will be obtained. It can be solved (provided the initial conditions are given). Then the substitution of the solution into the first and, say, third equations yields two inconsistent algebraic equations for z.

Comment: Looks like a cosmology problem, with the first two equations being the components of the Friedmann equation.  As @AlexeiBoulbitch notes, the third equation (wherever it comse from) is inconsistent with the Friedmann equation, and therefore with Einstein's equation, which means something weird is going on like non-conservation of the stress-energy tensor. You might need to go back to your physical model and see why this happens.

Comment: Should the main problem (already mentioned) be resolved, it'd be nicer if the parameters be given in code and, of course, to run `NDSolve`, one needs initial/boundary conditions.

Comment: @MichaelE2.Hi, the boundary conditions are`a[0]==0.001,a’[0]==1`. I made many runs or many trails actually. But I liked to ask here, to know the best way of solving.

Comment: Why do you keep saying `a[0]` and `a'[0]` where there is no `a[t]` in the odes's? I mentioned this at the top comment also.  Where does `a` come into play here? I do not see `a` anywhere. This is very strange. There is only `x[t]` and `z[t]`.

Comment: @Nasser:  In the cosmological context, the scale factor is usually given by $a(t)$.  For reasons unknown, the OP has renamed this `x[t]` in the code, but by force of habit keeps referring to the function as $a$.  So it goes.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert  I see. But for someone reading the code, this is very confusing, This should be really explained in the question. Looking at the code, I only see equations using `x` and `z` and see no `a`. But thanks for the explaination.

Comment: I would take the equations at face-value, ignoring the $a$ comments, do as Alexei says -- subtract third from second, get a second order DE in $x(t)$, solve the IVP problem in $x(t)$ with $x(0)=0.001$ and $x'(0)=1$, substitute that solution into the first to solve for $z(t)$.  Seems to me then solutions for $x(t)$ and $z(t)$ should then satisfy the third equation.

Comment: Fine, thanks for all the comments anyway. Yes of course I meant by a[t], x[t]. I will give it another try.